# marketing cloud advanced dynamic content email testing: sending all variations to one email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content-builder, send-email, personalization

I need to a send proof of a complex dynamic content email (20 variations) to a stakeholder on a monthly basis. I stumbled across a salesforce video that says I can create a data extension with black hole email addresses and use that to do an advanced guided send just for testing that will send all 20 versions of the email to one email address.

In my guided send I don't see a testing option. Is this video out of date or is it still relevant and my account just doesn't have this feature turned on? https://www.salesforce.com/video/297717/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Content Builder. If you open your email and select the Preview and Test tab, you can select the data extension with your dummy data, representing the different variations of data your recipients might have.

Instead of previewing and sending based on a single subscriber, you can select the entire data extension (in my example: 6 records) and have all the variations sent to one or more email addresses of your choice (not the email addresses in the data extension):

[image]

The popup will confirm, that 6 emails will go out, but all to one and same recipient: you (or whoever you choose to send to):

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Hi @Lukas Lunow, just curious, if I need to send the email proofs to a list of 10 stakeholders is there a way to do this easily? If I select a data extension or stakeholders as the recipients of this send the option "Based on Subscriber Preview of Testing_DE" is grayed out.